# Setting tagsToExclude in SBT

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

ScalaTest allows the setting of tags to be excluded via a filter called `tagsToExclude`.

How can I configure my SBT build to set this value?

**Attempt 1**

The CLI of ScalaTest specifies the `-l` flag for tags to exclude.

SBT allows the setting of CLI params like so:

```
testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument(
   TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-l", "DataFileTest")`
```

But this seems to have no effect (i.e. the test still executes).

For reference the test looks like:

```
object DataFileTest extends org.scalatest.Tag("com.mydomain.DataFileTest")

class MyDataFileDependantSpec extends FunSpec
                                with Matchers
                                with BeforeAndAfter
                                with BeforeAndAfterAll {

describe("Something") {
  it("reads a file and does things", DataFileTest) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
testOptions         in Test ++= Seq(Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest,
  "-l", "org.scalatest.tags.Slow")
```

This works.

See if the problem is to do with the full path name of DataFileTest.